# javascript JSON response formatting

Tags: javascript, json, api

Folks,
  Trying to understand returning and forming JSON responses.

The following code returns the object as a single string:

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Output to the browser:

```
{"Count":1,"Items":[{"dbsource":{"S":"x"},"number":{"S":"5002820"},"name":{"S":"blah,foo"},"expiration":{"S":"06/13/2015"},"type":{"S":"bar"}}]}
```

Dont I want the JSON output to be more readable, ie :

```
{
"one": "two",
"key": "value"
}
```

What should i change JSON.stringify(data) to?  Ideally I want the response to be used as an API endpoint.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd leave it alone, and then develop some sort of pretty-printer to be used by a client of the API.

Comment: I'm with Pointy.  If it's only going to be an endpoint, leave it the way it is and leave the formatting to whatever client is doing the consuming.

Comment: Folks, why not http://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend ?

Comment: Why not `JSON.stringify(object, null, '\t')`?

Comment: Using '\t' will spread out the printed json IMO.

Comment: @LightStyle oh well aren't you smart. :)

Comment: So if another person is writing a phone application which will query the API, which would he/she prefer?  A single string response, or something formatted?

Comment: @Clustermagnet well the insights of LightStyle and Deepak Mishra make my point irrelevant if not plain dumb, but my thinking was that JSON is mostly for machine consumption, and isn't very human-friendly no matter how nicely it's formatted.

Comment: Developers love colourful code. That's why use some javascript and regex or an equivalent library which does that for you.. as pointed out by @Pointy

Comment: @Pointy totally agree with you.. json is javascript's food.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Use stringify with spaces

```
var str = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
```

**The above string will have indentation with 2 spaces.**

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Can you please fix the reference?  404

Comment: fixed the reference. Thanks.